# A question regarding the metric space $(\mathbb N , d)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Give an example of a metric $d$ on $\mathbb N$  so that $n \to 1$  in $(\mathbb N , d)$.

Can anyone please tell me what is $n \to 1$ here ? I have really no clue.

Comment: $n \rightarrow 1$ means that the sequence $(n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $1$ in $d$, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(n, 1) = 0$.

Comment: discrete metric?

Comment: I am given only this. Nothing else is  there.  @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: I mean the discrete metric might be an example of such metric.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 It is not. Only constant sequences converge in the discrete metric.

Comment: $d(n,m) = \frac{1}{|n-m|}$  can be an example..@GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: @Shaqinho My bad, I confused $d(n,1) \to 1$ with $n \to 1$: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(n, 1) = 0$.

Comment: @sani This $d$ is not a metric since we want $d(n, n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: OkaY .. Define $d(n , n) =0 $  and when $n \neq m$ , $d(n,m) = \frac{1}{|n-m|}$. @Shaqinho

Comment: This does not fulfill the triangle inequality. I found an answer that I will write down.

Comment: Yes.. I also noticed that @Shaqinho

Comment: I literally just did this problem on an exam a few minutes ago... weird.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following: Let $\Phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be
$$
\Phi(x) := 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x=1 \\
\exp(-x) & \text{ else}
\end{cases}.
$$
Note that $\Phi$ is injective. We define $d: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $d(n, m) := \lvert \Phi(n)- \Phi(m) \rvert$.

Since $\Phi$ is injective, we have $d(n, m) = 0 \iff \Phi(n) = \Phi(m) \iff n = m$. Symmetry is obvious and the triangle inequality we get from the $\lvert \cdot \rvert$-triangle inequality.
Now let $n$ be very large:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(n, 1) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert \Phi(n) - \Phi(1) \rvert = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert \exp(-n) - 0 \rvert = 0
$$

This is, I admit, not a very elegant solution but it works.

**Remark:** If $\Phi$ is injective and arbitrary, then $d(x, y) = \lvert \Phi(x) - \Phi(y) \rvert$ always defines a metric on (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Beat me to it! I only did this problem a few minutes ago on an exam.

Comment: Lol :D I guess this question must be some kind of a "classic"...

Comment: Interestingly, I think the function $$\Phi(n)=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)$$ works as well.

Comment: Oh wow, this really might work. I mean it is injective.. That is one creative solution